# Syncing bookmarks in TBB?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, threat-models

Is it safe to sync bookmarks between multiple tor browsers using firefox's built-in sync feature? I'm using tbb on 3 different computers at this point and it's getting a bit annoying trying to keep all my bookmarks up to date.

I'm not clear on the threat model or risks involved with this subject.

Comment: There is an old ticket requesting this [#10368](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/10368), it has some links with information. Ultimately it will reduce your anonymity. We cannot make judgements about threat model, since it is specific to you and your use case and we have no information on either nor can we decide what is an acceptable level of risk for you and your use case. It will have serious drawbacks for anonymity though.

Comment: about:config - identity.fxaccounts.enabled - true

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think it does not depend to the TOR, but your FireFox account technically can know about the time and URL which you bookmarked. Therefore, can make a graph of your bookmarks and estimate your browsing and if FireFox cooperate with the web server which you've bookmarked it, your session at the web server can be identified and they can track what you did in the web site.

So, if you're concerning about the privacy, I suggest you to export bookmarks periodically from one browser and import it to the others. If it is not a problem, then feel free in bookmarking and syncing.